# Loading multiple tables from same dataflow in oracle data integrator

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-data-integrator

I have requirement of loading 100 bicc views into Oracle ADW. The mapping is straight forward and no transformations used . It is direct connection from source to target . I want to load all the 100 views data into 100 target tables without having to build 100 dataflows . Is there a way I can do that dynamically .

I tried using a parameter for data asset name but could not figure out how to do it loop.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.